# Pandas dataframe getting maximum and minimum by absolute value optimization

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, optimization

I have a large set of time series for which I am accumulating the maximum, and minimum values by absolute value in each time index. As an example of what I'm trying to accomplish, for data in two columns:

```
Data
[ 1, 2]
[-3,-4]

Max   Min
[ 2]  [ 1]
[-4]  [-3]
```

My current implementation is using these functions to determine which of two values has the higher absolute value (comparing squares was slightly faster than using the `abs()` function).

```
def max_abs(a,b):
    if(a**2 > b**2):
        return(a)
    else:
        return(b)

def min_abs(a,b):
    if(a**2 < b**2):
        return(a)
    else:
        return(b)
```

In the loop which runs through the data files after reading in the data from a .csv, the newest time series is copied into the temp data frame `tdf` under the `NewData` column. I then use the following commands to update the absolute maximum and minimum values.

```
tdf["NewData"] = inputdf["Waveform"]

tdf["Max"] = tdf.apply(lambda x: max_abs(x["Max"], x["NewData"]), axis=1)
tdf["Min"] = tdf.apply(lambda x: min_abs(x["Min"], x["NewData"]), axis=1)
```

Currently the latter two operations take ~0.4s for 10000 rows of np.float64 data, which is somewhat slow for the volume of data I need to process. I was wondering if there was a more efficient way for me to perform this task. I do have the option to multithread and parallel process this, but I'd like to optimize this process as much as possible before doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use numpy with indexing and for index of minimal and maximal values is used [`numpy.argmax`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) and [`numpy.argmin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html):

```
print (df)
    0   1
0   1   2
1  -3  -4
2  10 -12

arr = df.to_numpy()
arr1 = np.abs(arr)

Max = arr[np.arange(arr.shape[0]), arr1.argmax(1)]
Min = arr[np.arange(arr.shape[0]), arr1.argmin(1)]

print (Max)
print (Min)
[  2  -4 -12]
[ 1 -3 10]
```

Comment: Thanks! This is running about 10x faster than my pandas solution. Much more reasonable processing time now.

Answer (score 0):

You could sort the series and take the min and max value. For example:

```
def min_max_(l):
    l.sort()
    return {'min_abs':l[0], 'max_abs':l[-1]}
```

And for new_data you can run the function again for l+new_data or just for `new_data+[min_abs,max_abs]`